# Adding FrameLabels but without showing a Frame using GraphicsRow

Tags: graphics, labeling

I'm trying to create a set of plots that share similar axes (axes in the general sense, I'm actually using Frame). I'd like to have the text describing the axes plotted to the left of the first plot and centered below the row of plots (see code below).  I have tried using the option

```
FrameStyle->Directive[Transparent, FontColor->Black]
```

but this doesn't work as I'd expect.  Can anyone suggest a solution for this?

Thanks,

Mike

```
data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 10}];
Show[
 GraphicsRow[
  Table[
   MatrixPlot[data, AspectRatio -> Full,
    PlotLabel -> i,
    FrameTicks -> Automatic,
    ColorFunction -> (GrayLevel[1 - #] &),
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False
    ], {i, 3}]
  ],
 Frame -> {True, True, False, False},
 FrameStyle -> Automatic,
 FrameLabel -> {  "Position", "Amino Acid"},
 ImageSize -> 12*72]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Labeled`, which can be used to label almost anything, instead of `Show`.

```
data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 10}];
Labeled[GraphicsRow[
       Table[MatrixPlot[data, AspectRatio -> Full, PlotLabel -> i,
         FrameTicks -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> (GrayLevel[1 - #] &),
         ColorFunctionScaling -> False], {i, 3}],ImageSize -> 12*72], 
   {Style["Position", Bold], Style["Amino Acid", Bold]}, {Bottom, Left},
    RotateLabel -> True]]
```

The resulting plot is identical to that produced by the code in the question, apart from the labeling, which now is as desired.  Other `Style`s can be applied to the labels.

[image]

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks.  I haven't kept up with all of the changes in Mathematica so I was unaware of Labeled[].